# google in app billing how to set different prices of different wallpapers?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to use google in app billing to make my application sell able . In my app I have wallpapers some of which are free others have different prices I am really confused how to set different prices to different wallpapers because my whole application is one apk and I am not finding way to set different prices using the same apk. Is there a way out or am I missing any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange why i was unanswered but simply adding new products at in-apps menu solved my problem using different produid as SKU i could set differnt prices of different wall pappers
[image]